# .Net7 MAUI app unable to debug/publish with iOS16/Xcode 14

Tags: maui, .net-maui, .net-7.0

I can debug on MyMac (Mac Catalyst) no problem but not on the simulator, I get the following errors in the Application Output:

```
xcodebuild[4480:64944] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/wh/z7x5swm90fb6f6cxfp39760h0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2022-30-10_10-46-0020.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find simctl 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 16384: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

I'm using VS17.4 (preview 5 I think, how do I check? It just says 17.4 build 2339) and Xcode 14 for the iOS 16 SDK. I've checked in Preferences > SDK Locations > Apple and everything looks as it should... I'm a Mac noob so is there just a setting I'm missing somewhere?

If I try to build the release for publish like so VisualStudio crashes!

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-ios -c:Release
```

**Update:**

I just dropped back to net6.0 and am getting the same error. I didn't have Xamarin.Mac installed but installing it made no difference.

Below are some more component details of VS:

Xamarin.iOS Version: 16.0.0.72 (Visual Studio Community)
Xcode 14.0.1 (21336)
Xamarin.Mac Version: 8.12.0.2 (Visual Studio Community)

I can also see that the directory referenced does exist, or is it not supposed to look like that? [image: directory]

Comment: Can you check "Visual Studio" > "About Visual Studio"? Click the button "Show Details" should tell you more about different components. Edit the question to include that. In short, I cannot reproduce the issue you met though I am using the same VS for Mac version. I wonder if you something else is wrong on your Mac.

Comment: Thanks, I added a couple of version numbers, are there other relevant ones I should share?

Answer (score 0):

I had two version of Xcode installed which seems to have confused things. Uninstalling both then reinstalling 14 has fixed the issue.